# Why am I getting a route error after upgrading from Free to the u$49.-/month plan?

Tags: here-api

Trying to Optimize routes I still have the 10 routes limit per day, I need at least 100 per day.

How can I get rid of this limit?

Comment: I don't think either the Add-on or the Pro plan gives you additional transactions for the Waypoint Sequence API. Please check the plan details page (https://developer.here.com/pricing#plan-details) for more info. You can use the contact us button on the portal to get a plan that suits your needs.

Comment: Ive done this on 7th, today is 12th and nobody response. Will return to Free, the $49.- plan does nothing fro me and your support is really really bad.

Answer (score 1):

Waypoint Sequence API has 10 requests limit per day per APP_ID for both Freemium and Add-on plan. You can upgrade to Pro plan which has no restriction yet.

For Freemium and Add-on plans only, the following limits apply:

```
Custom Locations: you may upload a maximum of 3 layers with a maximum of 100 polygons or polylines.
Waypoints Sequence: up to 10 requests per day.
Advanced Data Sets: up to 100 requests per hour and 1,000 per day.
```

You can read more about the HERE Location Services limits [here](https://knowledge.here.com/csm_kb?id=public_kb_csm_details&number=KB0016408).

Comment: Waypoints Sequence: up to 10 requests per day.!!! is the same as Freemium, why waste $49/month, back to free inmediately.